# How to group array of hashes and create nested array after keyword?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

How to group array of hashes into one "groupname" and "id" hash and push elements occurring after "words" keyword into array of hashes? I can't find similar issue.

My flat input:

```
[{
    "id" => "1",
    "groupname" => "Unit 1",
    "words" => nil,
    "unit" => "1",
    "name" => "asdfwe"
}, {
    "id" => "1",
    "groupname" => "Unit 1",
    "words" => nil,
    "unit" => "1",
    "name" => "testasdf"
}, {
    "id" => "2",
    "groupname" => "Unit 2",
    "words" => nil,
    "unit" => "2",
    "name" => "test2wewe"
}, {
    "id" => "2",
    "groupname" => "Unit 2",
    "words" => nil,
    "unit" => "2",
    "name" => "test2sadf"
}]
```

Desired output:

```
[{
    "id" => "1",
    "groupname" => "Unit 1",
    "words" => [{
        "unit" => "1",
        "name" => "asdfwe"
    }, {
        "unit" => "1",
        "name" => "testasdf"
    }]
}, {
    "id" => "2",
    "groupname" => "Unit 2",
    "words" => [{
        "unit" => "2",
        "name" => "test2wewe"
    }, {
        "unit" => "2",
        "name" => "test2sadf"
    }]
}]
```

Current not working as expected steps:

```
out = []
arrhsh.each_with_index do |hsh,index|
  hsh.each do |(k,v)|
    if k === "words"
      newhsh = {}
      newhsh["id"] = hsh["id"]
      newhsh["groupname"] = hsh["groupname"]
      newhsh["words"] = []
      wordshsh = {
        "unit" => hsh["unit"],
        "name" => hsh["name"]
      }
      newhsh["words"] << wordshsh
      out << newhshq
    end
  end
end
out.group_by {|h| h["id"]}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: only group_by one key.

Comment: please include your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this?

```
b = a.group_by { |i| i['id'] }.map do |id, group|
  {
    id: id,
    groupname: group.first['groupname'],
    words: group.map { |g| g.slice('unit', 'name') }
  }
end
```

Comment: `g.slice('unit', 'name')` produces an error because there is no slice method in the Hash class. `words: group.map { |g| g.select { |k,_| k.match(/\bname\b|\bunit\b/) } }` fixes this problem.